# Detect Webpage in Facebook In-app Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-browser

I'm using npm package like Bowser to detect the Browser that I'm using when I'm opening a link. but When I try to open the link in my messenger. It still says that I'm using Chrome, but I'm on Facebook In-app Browser.

Is there any package to detect if using Facebook In-app Browser

Answer (score 1):

you can just create a helper function to do so:

```js
const isFacebookInAppBrowser = () => /FB_IAB/.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
  /FBAN/.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
  /FBAV/.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

This works for facebook in app but I am not sure for messenger. I didn't even know that it had a browser.

Comment: hello, would like to ask. how can I check this when I'm in fb in-app browser? it's false when I'm in chrome but I can't seem to check if I'm in fb in-app browser

Comment: this is part of your code so you just run it where you need it... your app is running on a browser so you can invoke that function as you would invoke any other. I don't quite understand the question

Comment: Hello for example I run that `{isFacebookApp == true ? (<div style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}> This is from Messenger Browser </div>) : ( <div style={{ marginLeft: "1rem" }}>  OTHER BROWSER </div> )}`

but when I tried opening it on facebook in app browser, it still shows chrome?

Comment: have you tried this?
```{/FB_IAB/.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
  /FBAN/.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
  /FBAV/.test(navigator.userAgent) ? (<div style={{ paddingLeft: "1rem" }}> This is from Messenger Browser </div>) : ( <div style={{ marginLeft: "1rem" }}>```

Comment: Hello just a follow-up question, how do you get the facebook in-app browser version?

Comment: Hi @PinkyPromise, have a look at the different user-agents that it uses, https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/facebook-app/ I never had the need to check for version but you can find patterns there and look for the version ;) I hope it helps